# Jhipster dynamically add button based on user role

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, jhipster

I am quite new to using react and have been struggling to dynamically add a button to a list based on the current user's assigned role.

the scenario is I want users to view some data only but if the user is an "ADMIN" then they can update and delete it. I would like there to be no button to update and delete if the user does not have the correct role.

most of the solutions I have tried point to the user not being available to check the details, so I am assuming that I have missed an import somewhere but not sure where this would be

```
<div className="btn-group flex-btn-group-container">
  <Button tag={Link} to={`${match.url}/${product.id}`} color="info" size="sm">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="eye" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">View</span>
  </Button>
  <Button
    tag={Link}
    to={`${match.url}/${product.id}/edit?page=${paginationState.activePage}&sort=${paginationState.sort},${paginationState.order}`}
    color="primary"
    size="sm"
  >
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="pencil-alt" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">Edit</span>
  </Button>
  <Button
    tag={Link}
    to={`${match.url}/${product.id}/delete?page=${paginationState.activePage}&sort=${paginationState.sort},${paginationState.order}`}
    color="danger"
    size="sm"
  >
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="trash" /> <span className="d-none d-md-inline">Delete</span>
  </Button>
</div>
```

This is the code I want to hide/show.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a method to check if the user is an admin like `isAdmin(user)`. If that is the case, you can just do `{ isAdmin(user) && <button>Admin Only Button</button> }`

Comment: no this is where my problem lies, I have a reducer file for user management, but no matter what I try to import i cant see any user information in my product.tsx file

Comment: Can you give an example of your Redux store state?